# Using Parallel.ForEach ParallelLoopState for loops, monitored etc

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

This is my function that received `List` of files and do my stuff:

```
private IEnumerable<string> _source;
public void doWork()
{
        ParallelLoopState pls = new ParallelLoopState();
        pls.LowestBreakIteration = 5;
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_source,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

I saw that this `ForEach` can receive `ParallelOptions` add i wonder how to use it in order to run this operation many times.

Comment: What do you mean by many times

Comment: run this several times\loops and monitoring (to know the current loop)

Comment: If you want to run a loop several times, why not use a while loop? i'm not really understanding the question.

Comment: You mentioned in my previous post about loop and monitoring so i wonder how this work cause i want to check it

Comment: In the previous post you mentioned you wanted an index in your loop, i simply showed you the overload of the Parallel.Foreach which takes a index inside the loop.

Comment: write and you said: "loop options can be configured, and the state of the loop can be monitored and manipulated" - can you show me how to use it in my function ?